# Page value doesn't get updated even though page is reset

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here is whats happening..

I have put reset button for resetting current page to 1.

Its working. But Page value is not getting updated. Here is my code. for pagination :

```
<pagination total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" class="pull-right" max-size="maxSize"></pagination>
```

Check out demo here : [Demo URL](http://demo.hupp.in/food-admin/)

Here are screen shots :

[image: Search Results - 1st Page]

Then I navigated to page 3.

[image: Page 3 results]

Then I reset page. It works but page value is not getting updated.

[image: Page is set to 1st but page value is not updated]

Tried to set..

```
current-page="currentPage"
```

but still it doesn't get updated.

Comment: There's not enough information for anyone to help

Comment: Could you provide JSFiddle or Plunker with your unworking part of code? We neeed to edit your example.

Comment: @ArtyomPranovich letting you know as soon as possible once I put it in plunkr.

Comment: @Shreejibawa ok, you can put into it only necessary functionality

Comment: @Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: @ArtyomPranovich : nope. still working on it. you can check it here : http://demo.hupp.in/food-admin/

Comment: What does you "Reset" code do? It looks like it is not present in your page anymore

Answer (score 0):

Looking in your page, it seems that your `ng-model` for the pagination is `page`.

So this should be enough:

```
// on click
$scope.page = 1;
```

If that doesn't work, there is a bug in the directive and maybe you should update it to the latest version.

Otherwise, if you really need to, you can get the directive scope and call `selectPage(1)` from it, which will work:

```
var paginationScope = angular.element('.pagination').isolateScope();
paginationScope.selectPage(1);
```

PS: note that you may need a `$scope.$apply()` to execute that if it outside of angular context.